TypeScript Error: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ courseId: string; }'
I am working on a Node.js project with TypeScript and facing an issue when I run tsc. The error I get is on user?.courses.push(course?._id); line :
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ courseId: string; }'

Here's the relevant code snippet:
export const createOrder = CatchAsyncError(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const { courseId, payment_info } = req.body as IOrder;

      const user = await userModel.findById(req.user?._id);
      const userId = req.user?._id as string;

      const courseExist = user?.courses.some(
        (course: any) => course._id.toString() === courseId
      );
      if (courseExist) {
        return next(
          new ErrorHandler("You have already purchased this course.", 400)
        );
      }

      const course = await CourseModel.findById(courseId);
      if (!course) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Course not found.", 404));
      }

      const data: any = {
        courseId: course._id,
        userId: user?._id,
        payment_info,
      };

      function generateOrderId(): string {
        const dateComponent = new Date()
          .toISOString()
          .slice(0, 10)
          .replace(/-/g, "");
        return `ORD-${dateComponent}-${Math.random()
          .toString(36)
          .substring(2, 8)
          .toUpperCase()}`;
      }
      const mailData = {
        order: {
          _id: generateOrderId(),
          name: course.name,
          price: course.price,
          date: new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
          }),
        },
      };

      const html = await ejs.renderFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "../mails/order-confirmation.ejs"),
        { order: mailData }
      );

      try {
        if (user) {
          await sendMail({
            email: user.email,
            subject: "Order confirmation",
            template: "order-confirmation.ejs",
            data: mailData,
          });
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
      }

      user?.courses.push(course?._id);

      await user?.save();
      await redis.set(userId, JSON.stringify(user));

      await NotificationModel.create({
        user: user?._id,
        title: "New order",
        message: `You have a new order for the course: ${course.name}`,
      });

      course.purchased ? (course.purchased += 1) : course.purchased;

      await course.save();

      newOrder(data, res, next);
    } catch (error: any) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  }
);

I am already using as IOrder to typecast req.body. However, TypeScript still complains about the type.
Here are some things I’ve checked:
My order model:
import mongoose, { Document, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "./user.model";

export interface IOrder extends Document {
  userId?: string;
  courseId: string;
  payment_info: object;
}

const orderSchema = new Schema<IOrder>(
  {
    courseId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    payment_info: {
      type: Object,
      // required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const OrderModel: Model<IOrder> = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

export default OrderModel;

Here is my user model
const emailRegexPattern: RegExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/;

export interface IUser extends Document {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  avatar: {
    public_id: string;
    url: string;
  };
  role: string;
  isVerified: boolean;
  courses: Array<{ courseId: string }>;
  comparePassword: (password: string) => Promise<boolean>;
  SignAccessToken: () => string;
  SignRefreshToken: () => string;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your name"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your email"],
      validate: {
        validator: function (value: string) {
          return emailRegexPattern.test(value);
        },
        message: "Please enter a valid email",
      },
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [false, "Please enter your password"],
      minlength: [8, "Password must be atleast 8 characters"],
      select: false,
    },
    avatar: {
      public_id: String,
      url: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    isVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    courses: [
      {
        courseId: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Hash password before saving
userSchema.pre<IUser>("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  next();
});

// Sign access token
userSchema.methods.SignAccessToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.ACCCESS_TOKEN || "", {
    expiresIn: "5m",
  });
};

// Sign refresh token
userSchema.methods.SignRefreshToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN || "", {
    expiresIn: "3d",
  });
};

// Compare password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (
  enteredPassword: string
): Promise<boolean> {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

const userModel: Model<IUser> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default userModel;

The req.body is coming from an Express request.
I tried adding type guards, but the error persists.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.

The user.courses structure expects all elements it contains to be of type { courseId: string; }. Currently, TypeScript does not know what the type of course?._id is and can therefore not verify that it meets the required type.
If you are sure the type you're receiving and the expected type are the same then you can cast the course?._id.
What is likely, is that course?._id is a String whereas user.courses expects an object with one String property. Therefore, place the ID into an empty object to resolve your issue. You can do this with:
user?.courses.push({courseId: course?._id});
See this similar issue for more information: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'
